# Is browser fully loaded check

Tags: javascript, pageload

Is there anyway to check if page is fully loaded.Something like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete.aspx but for JAVA.

Comment: by page you mean an html page?

Comment: Yes HTML page on any browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly in java, since it is probably not running in the browser, but you can do it with javascript

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">var myFunc = function() {
      alert("The page is fully loaded!");
    };
    window.onload = myFunc;
    </script>
  </head>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to execute logic on the client side when the page is loaded, you might be interested in the Javascript [`onload`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) event.

Or, even better, consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and use the [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function to execute your logic.

Just a short example using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("The document, including all assets such as images, has been completely received");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. JQuery will help you:**

there is `$(document).ready()` which tell you that the browser is loaded.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

The ready event occurs when the DOM (document object model) has been loaded, and the page has been fully loaded (including images).
Because this event occurs after the document is ready, it is a good place to have all other jQuery events and functions. Like in the example above.

**2.Window onload is another JavaScript approach:**

`window.onload=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode};`

The onload event occurs when an object has been loaded.
onload is most often used within the  element to execute a script once a web page has completely loaded all content (including images, script files, CSS files, etc.).

**Note: The main difference is that document.ready() event gets called as soon as your DOM is loaded. It does not wait for the contents to get loaded fully, while window.onload will wait until all your contents are loaded fully.

We can have more than one document.ready() function in a page where we can have only one onload function.**

Comment: Helpfully but the problem is that our project doesn't have to contain JavaScript,only Java.If we can mix them both using this JavaScript library in JAVA will be good.This seems helpfully    window.onload=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode};   but I'm not sure we can use it in our JAVA project.

Comment: ok.. but you have to use any on these. only java will not do boss.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the normal [onload()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp)

```
<body onload="yourFunctionHere()">
```

or the [JQuery version](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  yourFunctionHere();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in Java, no.
You'll need Javascript:

```
<script>  
  window.onload = function() {  
    alert('Loading Complete!');  
  }
</script>
```